# Is the 3.5 mm headphone jack of a Macbook Pro Retina also a line in port?

Tags: audio

The question is in the title of the post. :)

The Apple website says:

*3.5 mm headphone jack*

- *Support for Apple iPhone headset with remote and microphone*
- *Support for audio line out (digital/analog)*

Does this mean that the port is also a line in for the microphone?

Comment: Similar question here https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/90344/18101

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use the port as a line in. As detailed in [Apple's support article](https://support.apple.com/en-ca/HT201929),

1. Plug the input audio device into the combination audio port using
   the proper adapter cable.
2. From the Apple () menu, choose System
   Preferences.
3. Choose Sound from the View menu.
4. Click the Input tab.
5. Change the "Use audio for:" menu selection from Sound Output to the
   Sound Input.
6. The device type should change from "Internal
   Microphone/Built-in Input" to "Line In/Built-in Input."