# Can an iPhone 4S take microphone through audio jack?

Tags: iphone, audio, headphones, microphone

I can play audio of an iPhone 4S through the 3.5mm audio jack to headphones. I would like to use it with a headset that includes a microphone for making phone calls or recording audio. I'm not sure if it's compatible and have not found details from [the technical specifications](https://support.apple.com/kb/SP643?locale=el_GR).

Can I speak and hear a phone call on an iPhone 4S with a headset that includes a microphone through the jack 3.5mm line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does work for the standard earphones which are included when you bought an iPhone 4S so it's safe to assume that it works for other headsets as well, at least if their use of the audio jack is the same (which it should be, actually).

PS: See [this product listing on apple.com](https://www.apple.com/shop/product/MU982LL/A/urbeats3-earphones-with-35-mm-plug-black?fnode=1e22c077fd4bfec558bf4963bc41f7688203cf79824ba2e70cb3de1b26282e4fe5cf6458a63373a8268e16447f9161857cf0545b3936d312a42baed2e7328d849fe3851361d03c9748e387791e19cb705cd2ea979fddd779679138fde6366372f1e7a94b113e28b25778987ad5c66b068ff5f1c8093402ab123ac3019fe9f207) for an example.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use the audio jack on your iPhone 4S as a regular line-in port, but **only** with a special TRRS four-pole adapter! [This great answer is about the MacBook Pro](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/90545/18101) but it also applies to the iPhone audio port. Apple's [wired EarPods](https://www.apple.com/ca/shop/product/MNHF2AM/A/apple-earpods-with-remote-and-mic) don't need a special adapter because they already have the four-pole connector that allows both headphones and microphone line-in simultaneously.