# My MacBook recognizes my earphones as input device while Quicktime doesn't, how do I do?

Tags: headphones, quicktime, microphone

I've plugged my earphones to my MacBook. The OS recognizes the earphones' mic as an audio input device.

[image]

However, Quicktime screen recording doesn't seem to recognize that earphones' mic, how do I do?

Comment: What earphones are u using? Do they have a mic?

Comment: @X_841 yes, they have a mic that works well on the same device with Windows

Comment: Basically the earphones have to implement the microphone in the particular way that Mac recognises (called TRRS), and evidently yours does not. See https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/90344/macbook-pro-mid-2012-microphone-input/90545#90545

Comment: @O'Rooney thanks for your comments, I've updated my OP.

Comment: Oh, yes, that is a curious situation. Perhaps QuickTIme is using older (or newer) APIs that don't work fully.